# How to merge lists, received from 2 REST APIs with the `limit` and `offset` parameters, and receive result with `limit` and `offset` parameters too?

Tags: algorithm, rest, sorting, mergesort, array-merge

### Shortly

How to merge lists, received from two REST APIs with the `limit` and `offset` parameters, and return merged list as a result of calling the 3rd REST API also with the parameters `limit` and `offset`?

### Detailed

Given endpoints of two REST APIs like these:

```
GET api-1/events? limit=10 & offset=20
GET api-2/events? limit=10 & offset=20
```

Calling of these endpoints return ordered by date lists, for example:

```
api-1:
[
    { "date": "2024-02-11", "text": "magna aliqua" },    
    { "date": "2024-02-10", "text": "enim ad minim" },
    ...    
    { "date": "2024-02-01", "text": "quis nostrud" }  
]

api-2:
[
    { "date": "2024-02-11", "text": "exercitation ullamco" },    
    { "date": "2024-01-11", "text": "laboris nisi" },
    ...    
    { "date": "2023-04-11", "text": "aliquip ex" }  
]
```

It needs to write an endpoint for 3rd REST API like this:

```
GET api-3/events? limit=10 & offset=20
```

...that return merged ordered list by date of results `GET api-1/events` and `GET api-2/events` callings.

The problem has a simple solution for the first page (when `offset=0`), but for subsequent pages is necessary to make many requests to `api-1` and `api-2`.

### Questions

1. Does the problem have well-known name? I would google it in order to get closer to solving the problem.
2. How to develop `api-3` so that it works optimally enough:

   - to leave the ability to make API requests to `api-1` and `api-2` in parallel.

I know how to solve the problem in a simple way, but it will become more and more not optimal with the increase in the `offset` value.

Also, I have the option to change the way `api-1`, `api-2` and `api-3` work. I am inclined to replace the `order` and `offset` parameters with the `dateFrom` and `dateTo` parameters. This will solve the merging problem, but generates other problems on the API client side.